# Alert doesn't invoke popup when called inside .on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery and I'm using it to try to **execute some user scripts in Tampermonkey** to modify an existing website.

I want to click on an image to execute a function and wrote this small script to test it out.  The problem is that the alert method doesn't create a popup alert window when it's called within **.on**?  However, if I use the alert method "normally," then it works just fine?

My code is below:

```
var $ = window.jQuery;
$(window).load(function() {
    $('body').on('click','img',test);

    function test() {
      alert("Working Inside");
    };

    alert("Working Outside");
});
```

Interestingly enough, when I click on the image, the alert message does appear in Chrome's dev console?

Eventually, I'd like to replace the test function with this function:

```
function expandHeight() {
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i=0; i<ss.length; i++)
    {
        var rules = ss[i].cssRules || ss[i].rules;
        for (var j=0; j<rules.length; j++)
        {
            if (rules[j].selectorText === ".gadgets-gadget")
            {
                rules[j].style.height = "710px";
            };
            if (rules[j].selectorText === ".dojoxGridView")
            {
                rules[j].style.height = "660px";
            };
            if (rules[j].selectorText === ".dojoxGridScrollbox")
            {
                rules[j].style.height = "670px";
            };
            if (rules[j].selectorText === ".dojoxGrid")
            {
                rules[j].style.height = "670px";
            };
        };
    };
};
```

What this code does is expand the height of a Dojoxgrid data table so we don't have to scroll it to view more rows.

Comment: so what is and isn't happening? As far as I can tell, if that code is on your page then "working outside!" should pop up as soon as the page is loaded, and "working inside!" will when you click on the element. Certainly nothing should be printed to the console (other than an error perhaps, not that I see any obvious ones). So what exactly does and doesn't happen at various times, with that code?

Comment: Testing yout first piece of code, it is working as expected. No errors, when page loads, an alert appears with `"working outside"` and when click over an `<img>` it alerts `"working Inside"`, exact as it should do by using the code as you have

Comment: Thank you for testing Robin & Calvin!  "Working outside" does popup as soon as the website loads.  However, "Working inside" doesn't work.  I only see the message if I look in Chrome's Dev Console?  I am using this script inside TamperMonkey.  Did you test it inside TamperMonkey?

Comment: can you try `$('img').on('click', test);`

Comment: I never used TamperMonkey, can you provide a snippet or JsFiddle as a [mcve] so we can test and reproduce the error?

Comment: fila90:  Thanks, but that gave the same result.  No popup, only a message in Chrome Dev Console.  Calvin:  I'll try that when I get into work tomorrow.

Comment: Calvin:  Here's the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/gtwcxy7z/2/).  Inside and Outside both work when not in the window(Load) function.  But, I think we're supposed to use that function in TamperMonkey (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) so, I don't know if JsFiddle is an analogous environment for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to select the img element using JQuery in TamperMonkey using this format:

```
$("img#logo-img", parent.document.body).on('click', myFunction);
```